# Как использовать Google OAuth для PC приложения?

Tags: c#, oauth, google-oauth2

Вообщем пишу некий почтовый менеджер, OAuth авторизацию прохожу через client_secret.json но это только для 1 пользователя. Как авторизоваться под другим пользователем?
Вот как я делаю:

```cs
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart");

    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
}
```

Можно ли пройти аутентификацию OAuth по логину и паролю?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, авторизоватся по логину/паролю используя OAuth нельзя. Он для этого не предназначен, и такого механизма не предоставляет.

`client_id` и `client_secret` нужны не для использования API конечным клиентом. Они необходимы при запросе `токена доступа`.

Если по простому, то схема авторизации через OAuth выглядит так:

1. Ваше приложение отправляет на сервер OAuth(в вашем случае - принадлежащий Google) свой `client_id`, `client_secret`, и список требуемых приложению прав.
2. Сервер OAuth возвращает вашему приложению ссылку для авторизации клиента - ссылку на специальную защищенную страницу. В случае, если пользователь не авторизован - его перекидывает на страницу входа. Если авторизован - пользователю показывается список запрошенных приложением прав и дается выбор( согласится с ним или же нет).
3. Дальше в зависимости от типа приложения:

   - Веб-сайт:

     1. Пользователя переадресуют на полученную ссылку
     2. Пользователь подтверждает авторизацию приложения, либо отказывается от неё.
     3. OAuth-сервер напрямую отправляет результат авторизации(включая `токен доступа`, если она была успешна) на указанный вами сервер - это предотвращает его перехват на пути между клиентом и вашим сервером.
     4. OAuth-сервер переадресует пользователя на указанную вами страницу вашего сайта.
   - Устанавливаемое на устройство пользователя приложение(для этого типа приложений доступно меньше прав, и требуется специальная регистрация, т.к. данная схема авторизации гораздо менее безопасна)

     1. Открывается контрол веб-браузера, и в нем открывается полученная ссылка
     2. Пользователь подтверждает авторизацию приложения, либо отказывается от неё.
     3. OAuth-сервер переадресует пользователя на указанный вами псевдо-адрес, передавая токен доступа в строке url
     4. Ваше приложение перехватывает из url токен доступа, и закрывает контрол веб-браузера
4. Используя `client_id` и `токен доступа`, ваше приложение может выполнять запросы к требуемым API на серверах владельца OAuth-сервера.

Время действия токена доступа ограничено, поэтому при необходимости приложение может запросить `токен обновления`, с помощью которого можно получить новый токен доступа - необходимо для сокращения последствий компрометации токенов доступа.

Comment: А как используя OAuth получить доступ к разным Gmail аккаунтам? Какой класс использовать? Все никак не могу найти примеров.

Comment: @ИванСушков, абсолютно так-же, как и для одного. Просто проводите авторизацию несколько раз, получая токены доступа для разных аккаунтов - на странице авторизации приложения пользователь может выбрать какой аккаунт он хочет использовать.